# Adding a view to MVC that doesn't belong to a controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm not sure if the question title really explains what I want to do, however I will explain below:

I am using the Visual Studio MVC project template and I have changed some of the tabs to map to different actions from different controllers. However I want to make one of the tabs to open a view that will again have links for different administration actions.

The problem I have is that I am unsure where to place this view as it doesn't really belong to an admin controller as each tab on this view will link to a list view in another controller. In effect it is a sub _Layout view, as it doesn't have anything to do with a controller.

I hope I have made myself clear enough!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place this view in the Shared folder since it will be used by multiple controllers.  Or, you could place it somewhere else and reference it by using the full path to this View/Partial View

**In a Controller**

```
public ActionResult SomeAction(){
  return View("~/Path/To/View/ViewName.cshtml");
}
```

**In a View (Razor)**

```
@Html.RenderPartial("~/Path/To/View/ViewName.cshtml");
```

With that said, the Shared folder makes the most sense since it will be shared across multiple controllers.

Comment: Ok, but how would I access it as I only want it to show when a user clicks one of these tabs in the _Layout view? Currently I have only used ActionLinks such as `@Html.ActionLink("Contracts", "List", "Contract", new { user=User.Identity.Name, page=1 }, null)`, which obviously aren't the correct way in this case.

Comment: Are you asking how to have more than one layout (master page) views?

Comment: Sorry I think you actually already answered my question, I was getting tired last night, but now it makes sense! I was just unsure how to open access the view, but adding the `SomeAction()` method to my Hone controller will work as I want. Thanks.